# How do I delete item from listview I used ArrayAdapter<String> to display on listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Can any one tel me how to delete an item from listview .I used to database to store the content which has displaying in listview.To display on listview I make use of  ArrayAdapter .Now I want to delete item from listview .Actually it's deleting item only when clear database and restarted activity.Please help me to get solution.

Comment: Have you changed the items in adapter ... means the db items are changed or not..??  if simply list is not getting refreshed try adpater.notifydatasetChanged()

Comment: Ya the listview will get refreshed even though I did not used adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I can get adapter count value as and when I added items that is not issue ,just want to delete item from listview when user clicks on 'delete' button.

Comment: actually when we need to update listview on add or deleted items . we need to reset the adpter  .. In case of CusrorAdapter it gets auto refreshed from the cursor content..

Comment: You just want to delete the item from the listview or the database as well

Comment: From  both means from listview as well as database.@nick

Comment: ok.But I have used ArrayAdapter .I dont have much idea .Please help me.@ArpitGarg

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete any item from the **listview** then delete the source of **adapter** from where you are setting the data to the adapter and showing into listview.

For example,

I am setting the `ArrayList<String>` to the `ArrayAdapter` `adapter`
I am considering the data is collected into the arrayList.

**Now to Delete:**

```
arrayList.remove(pass the position here)
```

And then

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually now am able to delete but for every time i need clear database and restart activity then only it will delete that too only one time i mean first time if i restart activity without clearing DB it wont work only.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
void Reload()
{
    ArrayAdapter adapter= new  ArrayAdapter(context, ...);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```